# How to check word in android

Tags: android

example i have

String = "makan"

how to check last character is "n"
and character number 4 = "a"
and character number 3 = "k"

how to check third charcter of last word,
thanks

Comment: On Android? In which programming language you want solution?
Please Edit your question..

Comment: @makan, please search for answers before putting on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the strings method as

```
char c= "string".charAt(index);
```

To get the characters in the string.

**Edit**

You can get the string as array of char as-

```
String str = "string";
            char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: if i dont know index, example i input text with edittext, not only 5 character,   how to overcome them?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you are using, but in general read the character by index number (-1 because they start at 0) using []. Or with charAt like Sanjeet said.

Java:

```
String name = "makan";  
bool lastCharacterIsN = name[name.length - 1] == 'n';  
bool fourthCharacterIsA = name[3] == 'a';  
bool thirdCharacterIsK = name[2] == 'k';
```

Javascript:

```
var name = "makan";  
var lastCharacterIsN = name[name.length - 1] === 'n';  
var fourthCharacterIsA = name[3] === 'a';  
var thirdCharacterIsK = name[2] === 'k';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply like this.

```
    String _makan = "makan";
    int _length = _makan.length();

    System.out.println(" Index of n " +_makan.indexOf("n"));
    System.out.println("Length of String : " + _length);
    System.out.println("character at last : " + _makan.charAt(_length-1));
    System.out.println("character number 3  : " + _makan.charAt(2));
    System.out.println("character number 4: " + _makan.charAt(3));
```